# How should I manage url versioning in Django

Tags: python, django, versioning

I have a doubt about the optimal structure of my files.

Right now, I have all my urls in a file **`api.py`**.

The endpoints for a new version of the app are being located in a new **`api_v2.py`** file, only the urls that require a new version, is that ok?

Also, if a new functionality is added to the app, should I put the new urls directly on **`api_v2.py`**?  or maybe on the base **`api.py`** and keep the **`api_v2.py`** for the urls that have a "new version" of themselves?

**Any advice will help.**

Comment: In previous projects I worked on with multiple API versions, we actually did not do versioning within the application. We merely kept multiple git branches or repositories and managed routing by reverse proxy and path dispatching. Although, that's probably far from ideal, but it worked for us. I did find a [good writeup](https://gearheart.io/blog/api-versioning-with-django-rest-framework/) on the topic of using inheritence and it seems like a solid approach.

Comment: I'd suggest you prefix your new URLs with something like `/api/v2/URLL` or something. This way, in future if you decide to route new URLs to a different box or to a different app altogether, you can configure that at your webserver layer as well. And for your use case, yes, it seems good enough for me on what you are doing